# Color Highlight a select-string powershell

Tags: windows, command-line, powershell

I have a log file(.log) which is huge. I'm trying to find few keywords which need to be highlighted so that I can skip through other lines in the log faster. But, I don't want to filter only the select-string but highlight select-string. Also, I have no Idea about Powershell, I have the below command so far, from googling.

```
C:\users\proto> cat txtlog.log select-string "Valid" | write-host -foregroundcolor red
```

Which doesn't output what I want as it's only returning "valid" lines in red color but not the other lines.

Comment: A bit unclear on the output you want...example of source lines and desired output would help...

Comment: ValidLine 1
ValidLine 2
ValidLine 3
Someotherline x

So If I run the above command I get all valid lines in red color but Someotherline x is not shown. So, I need a way to colour validlines and also show Someotherline without colour.

Comment: So you want the whole (huge) logfile displayed? You're likely to exceed screen buffer size...

Comment: Something like `git diff --color-words` would do this. I don't know how to do that with PowerShell. The Format-Color function suggested gets closer.

Answer (score 5):

Add Format-Color function from [here](https://www.bgreco.net/powershell/format-color/):

```
function Format-Color([hashtable] $Colors = @{}, [switch] $SimpleMatch) {
    $lines = ($input | Out-String) -replace "`r", "" -split "`n"
    foreach($line in $lines) {
        $color = ''
        foreach($pattern in $Colors.Keys){
            if(!$SimpleMatch -and $line -match $pattern) { $color = $Colors[$pattern] }
            elseif ($SimpleMatch -and $line -like $pattern) { $color = $Colors[$pattern] }
        }
        if($color) {
            Write-Host -ForegroundColor $color $line
        } else {
            Write-Host $line
        }
    }
}
```

Then, pipe your output to Format-Color:

```
cat txtlog.log | Format-Color @{ 'Valid' = 'Red' }
```

Lines with the word Valid will be displayed in red while the others will be displayed in the default color.

Comment: Is it not possible to run it in just a command? Like, without any functions...

Comment: @FirstTimeUser I don't think you can currently accomplish it without implementing your own function(s).

Answer (score 1):

How about this???

```
$esc           = "$([char]27)"
$FormatWrapRed = "$esc[91m{0}$esc[33m"

txtlog.log | Get-Content | ForEach {
    If ($_ -match 'Valid') { $FormatWrapRed -f $_ }
    ELse {$_} 
}
```

Or (better IMHO) Add this filter definition to your profile:

```
Filter Wrap-Red {
    $esc = "$([char]27)"
    $WrapFormat = "$esc[91m{0}$esc[33m"
    If ($_ -match 'Valid') { $WrapFormat -f $_ }
    ELse {$_} 
}
```

Then in any console session, you can use:

```
txtlog.log | Get-Content | Wrap-Red
```

Or:

```
gc txtlog.log | Wrap-Red
```